# Swap image on keydown

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, keydown

I am looking for a way to swap to a different image when the user presses the down,up, left or right button. I have the following codes. What is the best way to approach this solution please?

Currently, my javascript is as follows. It moves to a different position depending on which key is being pressed. For example, if the 'down' button is pressed, the image moves down and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        // Left arrow key pressed
        case 37:
            $('.boat').animate({left: "-=50px"}, 'swing');
            break;
        // Up Arrow Pressed
        case 38:
            $('.boat').animate({top: "-=50px"}, 'swing');
            break;
        // Right Arrow Pressed
        case 39:
            $('.boat').animate({left: "+=50px"}, 'linear');
            break;
        // Down Arrow Pressed
        case 40:
            $('.boat').animate({top: "+=50px"}, 'swing');
            break;

    }
});

});
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — does it not work? *How* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Hello @nathantuggy! Sorry I wasn't being clear. It currently works. But it has the same image even though different buttons (left,down,up,right) are being pressed. I'm just looking for a way to swap the image when different buttons are pressed. Thank you!

Comment: You can use .hide() .show() or .toggle() to display different images

Comment: can you prepare a complete fiddle of this please?

Answer (score 0):

Before the answer, I notice that:the `which` in the JS document say : `Warning: This attribute is deprecated; you should use key instead, if available.`

Update :

I test your code and it works fine.

And you shold know :

Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) have no discernible effect on elements if their position style property is static, which it is by default.

So that is to say the element's position style property shold be `absolute` or `relative`

Comment: so what do you suggest and how can i improve and make it better? I just learnt this code via codeacademy!

Comment: You can use `which` also , and it's friends for the different browers.